# How to disable JavaScript at breakpoint like a media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `<header>` and  `<nav>` blocks that are affected by JavaScript. How can I create a JavaScript equivalent of a media query to disable all of this JavaScript code if the window is less than or equal-to 1200px wide?

My current JavaScript, with no instructions to stop running (last thing before `</html>`):

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>119)
         {
            $('header').fadeOut();
            $('nav').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
         }
        else
         {
          $('header').fadeIn();
          $('nav').css({position: 'absolute', top: 'auto'});
         }
    });
</script>
```

I've tried wrapping the code with

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1200) {
    // scripts
}
```

and

```
if (screen.width <= 1200) {
    // scripts
}
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrapping the code is the correct approach. Since you're already using jQuery, you can do

```
if($(window).width() > 1200) {
  // the rest of your code goes here
}
```

Notice that I'm using `>` instead of `<=`, since you want to run it if it's greater than 1200px, and you want it to be ignored if it's less than or equal to 1200px.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code:

```
<script>
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if(windowWidth >= 1200)
    {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop()>119)
            {
                $('header').fadeOut();
                $('nav').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            }
            else
            {
                $('header').fadeIn();
                $('nav').css({position: 'absolute', top: 'auto'});
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```